# Ansible запуск несколько apt install на одном хосте - ошибка

Tags: развертывание, ansible, devops, apt

Приветствую!
Создал роль в которой в inventory файле прописано несколько груп хостов с разным функционалом. Чтобы не засорять привожу выдержку из кода:

```
[elasticsearch]
dev-elastic-01   ansible_host=192.168.37.10
[kibana]
dev-kibana-01   ansible_host=192.168.37.10
[logstash]
dev-logstash-01   ansible_host=192.168.37.15

main.yml
- name: Update repositories cache and install {{app.name}} package
  sudo: yes
  apt:
     name: "{{item}}"
     state: installed
     update_cache: yes
 with_items: "{{app.name}}"


app.name указан в group_vars(kibana, elastic, logstash)
group_vars/elasticsearch
app:
   name: 'elasticsearch'
```

В роле запускаю установку программы с помощью модуля apt. Если в inventory файле указывать разные адреса для хостов проблем не возникает, но если указать одинаковый адрес хостов(Например, хочу чтобы на одном хосте был и фронтенд, и бэкэнд) - возникает ошибка блокировки файла

```
Failed to lock apt for exclusive operation
```

Насколько я понимаю из-за того, что роли выполняются паралельно, в один момент идет обращение к установщику, который уже занят другим процессом. Как можно запустить установку последовательно? Честно говоря, идеи закончились. Может кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой. Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, роль не может содержать инветарь – у вас есть отдельно: роль, плейбук и инвентарь.

Теперь по сути вопроса: использование разных имен для одного и того же целевого сервера является хаком, который иногда применяется, если никак не уложиться в стандартную группировку переменных в инвентаре. Если вы так делаете и при этом есть конфликтующие таски (например, `apt`), единственный выход – `serial:1` в этом плее, но это сильно замедляет исполнение при большом количестве хостов.

Обычно же для цели, которую вы хотите достичь...

> Например, хочу чтобы на одном хосте был и фронтенд, и бэкэнд

...используют разные роли + разные группы.

Т.е. в вашем случае должны быть:

#### три роли

1) kibana

2) elastic

3) logstash

4) возможно, параметризуемая роль base-app (которую вышеперечисленные вызывают с параметром app_name)

#### инвентарь с группами

```
dev-host1 ansible_host=192.168.37.10
dev-host2 ansible_host=192.168.37.15

[elasticsearch]
dev-host1

[kibana]
dev-host1

[logstash]
dev-host2
```

#### плейбук для применения ролей к группам

```
- hosts: elasticsearch
  roles: [elastic]
- hosts: kibana
  roles: [kibana]
- hosts: logstash
  roles: [logstash]
```

Comment: Спасибо, Константин! 
Первую рль для установки елка - писал с помощью разных ролей, но сказали написать универсальную, ну переделал. Пока использовал докер контейнеры проблем не возникало, но как нужно было написать для Дебиана и с установкой пакетов возникла такая проблемка. 
Структура проекта:
    group_vars:
          elasticsearch
          kibana...
    roles: -> task -> main.yml -> use_apt.yml
Отдельний inventory файл  и отдельный плейбук в котором указаны таски. Тоже смотрел в сторону serial, но толком не разбирался, так как будет медленно. Т.е. вариант один - разделять на роли.